# Creating Node.js/Express/EJS etc app... In my views dir I have my home.ejs, and an index.ejs that are identical. Why wont my home.ejs display css?

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

This has caused me so much hell. I find that the problem I'm having is my `home.ejs` file, with the route set to `'/'`. The page displays without any CSS.

It doesn't matter which EJS view I route to with the (`'/'`) forward-slash get route... THAT view will not display the CSS properly coded into `<head>` which is properly in the partials and included.

Attempting to find the problem, I created an `index.ejs` in my views dir, copy and pasted all code from `home.ejs` so they were identical. I set the route `'/index'` for `index.ejs`. Now when I load my `http://localhost:3000/` I see `home.ejs` without css.

`http://localhost:3000/index` though gives me the css and page I want. What is going on here?

*Here are images of my code:*

- [My Proj Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5WfO.png)
- [My 'index.js' (JavaScript) file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnENd.png)
- ['home and index 'ejs' files side-by-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0niL1.png)

This is my first time posting a question. Sorry if I organized my question horribly... Thanks in advance for any help

To summarize what seems the issue... If I attempt to use the basic `get('/')` route for any .ejs file, no css is displayed

EDITED: Here's my links code:

```html
  <!-- Link Google Font Stylesheets-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

  <!-- Link Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Link Custom CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css"> 
</head>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: Please also [edit] your question to include the `<link>` tags you're using for the CSS. Taking a guess, you probably have relative paths when they should be absolute, ie `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" />`

Comment: I added the code above

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue with the code you provided and I cannot, so I wonder what else is going on,

but first to understand whats actually happening we need to know:

when you say " I see home.ejs without css.",

can you go to the network tab in your browser developer settings (right click page -> inspect) and check, is the css trying to load? maybe the partial is being included but it 404's to the css?

or maybe the partial is not being loaded at all? also check the "elements" to see if the html is being included or not. This will help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem.

In public you have included a file 'index.html'

This file and its CSS (or lack of) will be loaded when you load `localhost:3000`. (Due to you setting up express.static over that directory). Any other route (e.g. `localhost:3000/index` will load your ejs views.

So it seems like perhaps `index.html` has some styles you need to copy over to your partial?